# Safari is displaying Times New Roman for all fonts in Safari 5.0.x

Tags: safari, webpage-rendering

My site is displaying all fonts in Times New Roman even though that declaration is nowhere in my CSS.

This only happens in Safari 5.0.5 on OS X only. When inspecting a text element, it says "font-family: Times New Roman".

The fonts are displayed correctly in 5.1

What could be the problem, and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no fonts declared in your CSS, The browser may try to apply its default font.

To avoid that, you may do something like:

```
html{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Verdana;
}
```

However, If you do have `font-family` declared for your element, it may be some widget or external CSS that overwrites your CSS, Try to get rid of these for a quicker debugging.

Comment: We've narrowed it down to some weird issue with the build script.