# Input text box in IPad safari browser showing times new roman as font

Tags: css, ipad, textinput

I am working on a website. Viewing the site in IPad is always showing font Times New Roman with i guess font-size 6 or 7. Though i have never mentioned this font in my css. Rest all labels are coming up fine in 'Segoe UI' font as expected. The site is working fine in Desktop browsers, even i safari on my desktop. But for IPad, its showing Times New Roman.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-el) link's plugin and seen the output in an alert, its showing fontFamily as 'Segoe UI' only but the font is not that.

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391159/safari-is-displaying-times-new-roman-for-all-fonts-in-safari-5-0-x) but not working.

Also tried putting up inline style with !important attribute in css, but same.

Can somebody help me on what am i doing wrong or what i might add/remove to correct the behavior?

EDIT:
Code i tried separately [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rFrpu/) is also not behaving expected on my IPad atleast, its not showing Segoe UI as font for sure. But in my desktop browser its showing Segoe UI.

```
<input type="text" value="imjgnsdnbf" style="font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:20px;" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Could this be my IPad specific setting?

Comment: Can you include code in the question that allows us to reproduce this problem?

Comment: added a link to the simplest code that's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segoe UI is a windows font, and ipad is apple product!

So you have to include the font with something like [font-face](http://www.font-face.com/)

***Edit**
To select a input field in css

input[type=text]

Comment: Simon, In that case - How is it other controls like labels are showing the font fine?

Comment: their shouldn't be any difference in how they look what about just styling trough css?? see my edit how to select a input text field

Comment: Simon, i know how to style things, how to select input type text etc. and I can also use font face (though i am not able to find a site hosting 'Segoe UI' for free :) ), but what i am saying is, how is it the rest of the site is working fine in IPad.